# Migrating from Artifactory to Sonatype Nexus 3

Tags: maven, migration, nexus, artifactory, sonatype

I'm trying to migrate my artifactory repository to nexus 3, but following sonatype's recommendation, it just shows me how to migrate nexus 2, and from what I've seen, the file system structure is different between versions of nexus.

Has anyone managed this migration yet?

I couldnt find anything in the nexus migration documentation 3.

Here is the link I used from the sonatype site on migration: http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/02/23/migrating-from-artifactory-archiva-or-a-raw-maven-repository-to-sonatype-nexus

Comment: Nexus 3 uses so called blobs to store the repository data and there is a migration between Nexus 2  to Nexus 3 described...But apart from that if you are on a Nexus Pro why aren't you contacting Sonatype?

Comment: it was a typo, I'm not using nexus pro =/

Comment: from what I saw, the migration plugin was discontinued on nexus 3, so I dont know how to do this migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until NXRM3 implements an import ability, the recommended strategy I've heard is to migrate Artifactory to NXRM2 then migrate your NXRM2 to NXRM3.

Depending on what components you use, you may also be able to script the components from Artifactory directly to NXRM3 using stuff like this: http://exchange.sonatype.com/details?extension=4969301365

However, this won't work for all components, like probably won't work for docker.  That's not to say you couldn't write something that would work but the linked strategy wouldn't work.

For import, you can watch/vote [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11468).  I envision it'll be possible once that's done, however, won't be sure til it's done=)

Comment: thanks @joedragons! this script is so simple and helped me a lot.